# Edit row in list Error: Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, error

Has anyone else come across a Javascript (KO) error in SharePoint Online where you try to save a unedited list and it comes up with this

[image: SharePoint edit error]

You can see by the image that I haven't added any on my own lists or site columns so am only using the default "Title" and "Attachment" fields.

Basically if you don't try to change a field and press save, you will get the error, if you change one field and press save it will work fine.

For more info, this error doesn't occur in quick edit nor does it happen in classic mode (in both quick edit or detail edit) so I believe it's in the new SharePoint style.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I can reproduce the issue. In the new experience, when I edit the item and save without change, I receive the same error as yours.

In the new experience, if there is no change when you edit the item, you could click Cancel button instead of Save button.

And you could consider using the classic experience.

After all, you could submit the feedback about the issue through the link below.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks. Indeed there are workarounds. Just glad it wasn't just my environment.